# Error when I deserialize Xml by simple-xml library?

Tags: java, android, xml, deserialization

I used "simple-xml-2.7.1.jar" library in my deserialization class but when I write `read` method,  compiler show me this error:

> "Default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception thrown by
>   implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor".

```
public class DeserializeXml  {

    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    File source = new File("example.xml");
    Project project = serializer.read(Project.class,source);
}
 @Root(name="Project")
    public class Project {
    @Attribute(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Attribute(name = "location")
    private String location;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Xml Code:

```
  <Project name="projectForAndroid"location="C:\Users" Description="Description">
    *****
    *****
  </Project>
```

Comment: plz post Project class and xml if possible

Comment: I have xml after that when i try read by this method the compiler show me error.

Comment: `desalinization`? Do you want to make it **drinkable**?

Comment: You didn't omit any "extends XXX"?

Comment: no i didn't do any extends.